# Javascript Properties

Tags: javascript, function, oop

Please let me know if question is just dumb and not answerable?

I've just started unit testing with javascript. I have been implementing [this](https://nicolas.perriault.net/code/2013/testing-frontend-javascript-code-using-mocha-chai-and-sinon/) blog code into my app. I just confused with name argument being passed to function in javascript. If we talk about Java,Php or any other language they take arguments in construct function and is understandable to use within class something like

```
$vehicle = new Vehicle('argument here');

Class Vehicle {
    protected  $name;
    function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name; // we can use the property any where in the class
     }
}
//Is name Property? Object? or anything else?
//javascript
(function(name) {
    "use strict";
    function vehicle(modal) {
        this.modal = modal || 'Civic 2015'; 
    }
    name.vehicle = vehicle; //? ? ?
})(this);//also why using (this) ?
```

Also an example would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: Please, read a good tutorial on OOP in JavaScript. There is one available at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have class (really) and so OOP is handled slightly differently to some of the languages you mention. Often you'll see something like this:

```
function Vehicle(make, color){
    this.make = make;
    this.color = color;
}

Vehicle.prototype.getMake = function(){
    return this.make;
}

var myCar = new Vehicle('ford', 'green');
myCar.getMake(); //'ford'
```

As shown in this fiddle I made: https://jsfiddle.net/eqf2apwx/

There are many ways to handle JS objects, however, and I'd suggest you google it a bit, particularly 'Crockford Classless' which is a popular way of handling objects.

Answer (score 0):

The function that you are using above is called self-executing immediate functions, "this" inside such functions always points to the global object, because inside functions that were invoked as functions (that is, not as constructors with new) "this" should always point to the global object.

This pattern is useful because it provides a scope sandbox for your initialization code. Think about the following common scenario: Your code has to perform some setup tasks when the page loads, such as attaching event handlers, creating objects, and so on. All this work needs to be done only once, so there’s no reason to create a reusable named function. But the code also requires some temporary variables, which you won’t
need after the initialization phase is complete. It would be a bad idea to create all those variables as globals. That’s why you need an immediate function—to wrap all your code in its local scope and not leak any variables in the global scope

However, in ECMAScript 5 in strict mode, "this" reference doesn't necessarily point to the global object so you have to adopt a different pattern when your code is in strict mode. Therefore, developers usually pass the reference to "this" from the global scope. SO in your case "this" which is passed as an argument to immediate function is a reference to the global "window" object. Also, this pattern makes the code more interoperable in environments outside the browser because you don't need to hardcode "window" inside the immediate function.